# YQL don't provide Indian stock quote related data

Tags: jquery-ui, c#-4.0, yql, yahoo-finance, stockquotes

we are very interested to use YQL but unfortunately the query is not supported for Indian stock market , we are building one large web app where wee need to show BSE and NSE tickers with live updates , so we thought to use yahoo financial services but I have tried a lot in the console the below line but this is return with zero data

select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN("^BSESN")

For that result we can't able to use yql , I have also change the symbol ^BSESN with other Indian company names like reliance ,tata but nothing is shown, feeling very poor......

select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol IN("^BSESN") ---- not working any idea or suggestion will helpful to me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo's YQL shows uneven performance for bourses outside the West. For example:

You can obtain historical data for Reliance Industries from yahoo.finance.historicaldata using YQL as follows: select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in ('RIL.BO')

You cannot get stock quote from yahoo.finance.quotes using YQL as follows: select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("RIL.BO")

Try it!